# 550 Error when connecting to FTP server. Only occurs with C#

Tags: c#, ftp

I'm trying to write a program in C# that will FTP into a machine, download some logs, and then delete the logs off of the machine. This process works with a dev FTP server I have to test on my machine but when I try to connect to the production server I want this program to be used on I get a "550 No files found or invalid directory or permission problem" error on the server.

The server will list the directory file for FileZilla, even when using the exact same URI. I have captured the packets with wireshark and the server just cuts off after sending the text "total" to the data port when trying it with C#

```
Uri uri = new Uri("ftp://username:password@10.205.205.200:21/");               
FtpWebRequest ftpWebRequest =  FtpWebRequest)WebRequest.Create(uri.ToString());

ftpWebRequest.Method = WebRequestMethods.Ftp.ListDirectoryDetails;

// Get the response
FtpWebResponse response = (FtpWebResponse)ftpWebRequest.GetResponse();

// Get the stream and reader
Stream responseStream = response.GetResponseStream();
StreamReader reader = new StreamReader(responseStream);

// Close the response
response.Close();

// Get all the results into a list
List<string> results = new List<string>();
results.AddRange(reader.ReadToEnd().Split('\n')); //<---- Web Exception Here
```

Comment: Why are you calling `response.Close()` before trying to read the stream?

Comment: Closing the response closes all the streams associated with that response...

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Please try it this way:

```
Uri uri = new Uri("ftp://username:password@10.205.205.200:21/");               
FtpWebRequest ftpWebRequest = (FtpWebRequest)WebRequest.Create(uri.ToString());
ftpWebRequest.Method = WebRequestMethods.Ftp.ListDirectoryDetails;

using (FtpWebResponse response = (FtpWebResponse)ftpWebRequest.GetResponse())
using (Stream responseStream = response.GetResponseStream())
using (StreamReader reader = new StreamReader(responseStream))
{
    List<string> results = new List<string>();
    results.AddRange(reader.ReadToEnd().Split('\n'));
}
```

In general it is safest to use `using` when dealing with streams or other disposable resources.

Comment: That works! Thanks! I swear when I looked it up the web response didn't implement IDisposable but I guess I must've misread. Do you have any clue as to why my code would've worked on my local FTP server?

Comment: @AlexDay, your question made me realize my original solution was only half right - in that there are 3 resources in your case that are `IDisposable` - I've updated the answer to use `using` with all 3 of these. Not sure why it would have worked on your local FTP server the way it initially was. Perhaps the response was obtained and cached because it was local? That is only a guess.